# When the value of the sub key is deleted or How to prevent the deleting - vsix

Tags: vsix, regedit, ssms-2017

In `vsix-package` extension for SSMS I have problem -
 after the `Initialize` function the value of the sub-key is deleted (in the registery edit) and it causes that if I open the SSMS several times in a row, the extension is loaded only to the first instance of the SSMS.
I know the deleting happens between the function `Initialize` and the event `DTEEvents_OnStartupComplete`
What can I do in order to prevent the deleting or when is the value  deleted?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You need to have your extension whitelisted, all other extensions will not run under SSMS

Comment: Can you explain what the connection to my question? I didn't understand what you meant-Thank you Ron

Comment: Your extensionId must be on list of ids known by SSMS, or it will refuse to load it...

Comment: The extension is loaded but after the Initialize the value in the sub -key is deleted and I need to write it again for the next time